# Both result and exception from java method call

Tags: java

I've got weird java behavior. At first I thought it is a bug of debugger, but I see effects of the same behavior in production code. In the attached screenshot I'm at break point in the catch block, but somehow result of the method which thrown exception is also in place (`n = 4` and `buf` has 4 bytes written). As far as I know this should not happen. Can someone explain how is this possible and how to avoid such behavior? The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/io/StreamCopyThread.java). The `src` field is `java.io.PipedInputStream` from standard library.

[image]

Comment: The most likely explanation is that code on the server, and your version is slightly out.  Even so it is odd that you can see `n` and `wakey`. I would also check this happens on an non EAP version.

Comment: @Codebender no, it's fine since in the case when exception is thrown we don't reach `if (n < 0)` line, due to `continue` in the catch block.

Comment: @Codebender it compiles due to the `continue;` on line 128.

Comment: Just saw it...:) thanks...

Comment: @PeterLawrey I can reproduce it locally, no server is involved. I've checked on several jdk versions: 1.7.0-21, 1.7.0-67, 1.8.0-20.

Comment: Is it possible that `n` was 4 before `src.read`? Maybe it isn't initialized back to `0` after previous iteration of loop? And buffer is filled before exception occur.

Comment: @talex nope since `n` is `final`.

Comment: @neverov If you can reproduce it can you post bit of code that reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @neverov Yes it is final, but JVM could decide to reuse stack slot without cleaning it since it will be initialized in assignment or never reed.

Comment: @talex you are probably right, it seems like the value of n is there from previous iteration, jvm is reusing a stack location, that's why debugger shows the value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency in your code. Since `n` is defined outside the try block, it is in scope during the execution of the except block.

Besides, you are treating the interruption and continuing the loop without any further ado. Therefore, the program flow shoud also continue.

If you want your code to be interrupted, you should throw an interruption and make the ones who call your function catch it. If you want a return value that denotes an error, you need to encode it in your domain (for instance, if `n` represents the number of non zeros received, you could return a negative number in case there is an exception).